# Angular - pdf document using iFrame

Tags: angular, pdf

I have embedded  PDF document using iFrame on Angular application.
The document is open by native Chrome PDF viewer.
Is there a way that PDF document will be open using Adobe Acrobat Chrome extension -( where its installed)  ?
I know that using Adobe API it can be achieved but I am looking for another approach or solution.